# Kivy output screen is blank

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner in Kivy. I was just writing a simple code when I got stuck, and when I am trying to run the code, the output screen is blank. Heres the code:

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.metrics import dp


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

Kivy code:

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Button"
        size: "400dp", "200dp"
        pos: "100dp", "200dp"
        color: 0, 1, 1, 1
    Label:
        text: "Label"
        size: "100dp", "80dp"
        pos: "550dp", "300dp"
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build on this code.

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Hmmmm thnx but i have already solved my problem. Actually you had to write your kivy files name in the class. Everything else was fine.